# How to combine multiple commands into a nested loops?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have three commands in one shell script: `wget`, `7z`, and `rm`.

Inside list.txt

```
URL1 archive_01.zip  
URL2 archive_02.zip  
URL2 archive_03.zip
```

Download archives:

```
while read -r url filename; do
    wget -O "$filename" "$url";
done < list.txt
```

> $ ls
>   archive_01.zip
>   archive_02.zip
>   archive_03.zip

Extract archives:

```
for file in *zip; do
    7z x $file;
done
```

> $ ls
>   archive_01.zip
>   archive_02.zip
>   archive_03.zip
>   folder_01
>   folder_02
>   folder_03

Delete archives:

```
rm *zip
```

Is it possible to make these three commands into a nested loops? If so, how?

I'm also curious, because the commands above will be executed like this (if I'm not wrong):

> Download URL1 > Download URL2 > Download URL3
>   Extract Archive1 > Extract Archive2 > Extract Archive2
>   Delete Archive1 > Delete Archive2 > Delete Archive3

how to make the execution be like this?

> Download URL1 > Extract Archive1 > Delete Archive1
>   Download URL2 > Extract Archive2 > Delete Archive2
>   Download URL3 > Extract Archive3 > Delete Archive3

Comment: Still not familiar with this kind of thing. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#! /bin/bash -

while read -r url filename; do
    wget -O "$filename" "$url"
    7z x "$filename"
    rm -- "$filename"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: I didn't know it so simple haha. Thank you for the answer 

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r url filename; do
  wget -O "$filename" "$url";
  7z x $filename
  rm $filename
done < list.txt
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Is it that simple? Haha one more question, it will executed as `Download1 > Download2 > Download3` or `Download1 > Extract1 > Delete1`?

Comment: @Hidayats  put `#!/bin/bash -x`  will give you more details. See it yourself.

Comment: @val0x00ff already put it but nothing happened. `$ bash -x script` works well.